# How to get return value from javascript in xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms. I have a javascript method in a html file that returns a value. I need to access that javascript method and get the return value. I tried to use WebView. But unfortunately the webview.Eval() method doesn't return any value. It is Void type.

Please tell me how I can access the javascript method with help of webview and will get the return value of that functions.

Comment: Hi @anand, do you got any idea for this need?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exist yet, but it looks like it's coming in the next Release of Xamarin.Forms:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/commit/578c0eb23a719926f90f0fd45ff1659512bb9bed